# How can I construct an equivalence relation in the form of a 0-1 matrix from a set partition?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I have a partition of a set `{1, 2, ..., n}`. I would like to construct the equivalence relation that corresponds to the set partition in the form of an $n \times n$ 0-1 matrix. How can I construct such matrix?

For example:

```
(* Input *)
{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}

(* Expected Output *)
{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first create all pairs of elements in each of the equivalence classes by [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), then feed these indices to a [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
partition = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}} 
Normal@SparseArray[Catenate[Tuples[#, {2}] & /@ partition] -> 1]
(* {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
parts = {{4, 7, 6}, {5}, {8, 1}, {9, 2, 3}}
perm = PermutationMatrix @ Flatten @ parts; 
mat = Transpose[perm] . BlockDiagonalMatrix[
         (Table[1, {Length[#1]}, {Length[#1]}] & ) /@ parts] . perm; 
MatrixForm[mat]
```

results in

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

For a larger example instead of conjugating by the permutation matrix it is probably faster to actually permute the rows and the columns using the permutation that sorts the entries in `Flatten @ parts`.

Answer (score 0):

Should your example not read: {{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1}}

If yes, you may write:

```
n = 4;
pos = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}};
Normal[SparseArray[Thread[pos -> 1], {n, n}]] + 
  IdentityMatrix[n]  // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Addendum

To make the matrix symmetrical, write:

```
n = 4;
pos = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}};
pos = Join[pos, Reverse /@ pos];
Normal[SparseArray[Thread[pos -> 1], {n, n}]] + 
  IdentityMatrix[n]  // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: The matrix has to be symmetric, as it is supposed to represent an equivalence relation

Comment: Look at the addendum in my answer.

Comment: In any case, I think you misunderstood the meaning of the input. It could well be {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}}.

Comment: I understood {1,4} to mean row 1 and column 4 is "1".   Or element 1 and 4 are equivalent